# Rundeck run job when file is detected

Tags: automation, rundeck

Does anyone know if its possible to have Rundeck (or another open source scheduler) kickoff a job based on a file being detected on it's filesystem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ProActive, an open source scheduler, we developed a small script that would allow you to do that and check the changes in a folder for a selected period.

[Directory Monitoring Script](https://gist.github.com/fr3nchN/826a4e494e6c6e49ea895c3e29c54e9b)
Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Thanks, actually ended up using Jenkins instead and the FSTrigger platform but good to know there are alternatives if we have issues